# Adding dynamically current year in a Label in LaunchScreen.xib in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode9, launch-screen

Is it possible to add the current year dynamically to a Label to show **"Copyright current year"** in the LaunchScreen.xib in iOS using Objective C? If yes, could you please write the steps needed?

From my knowledge, I think the LaunchScreen is only to display static contents but after going through few articles they said it can be done but I didn't get a clear answer. I know this is a duplicate question in StackOverflow but still hoping to get some help. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can't display any dynamic content inside the launch screen , but you can create a splashVC as the rootVC that you add to it what you want and by setting a timer/ dispatch / delay inside that splash to navigate to the mainVC of the app